# Passing (this) between functions

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to extend one rectangle using a drag handle without altering the other rectangles.  I've tried to pass on the selected one using (this) but I can't get it to work.  http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/gmLaY/  -drag right hand black bar.   Any help with this issue or alternatives?

```
var dragright = d3.behavior.drag()
     .origin(function() {
         var t = d3.select(this);
```

Comment: what do you want this to refer to? `d3.behavior.drag().origin()` or `d3.behavior.drag()`?

Comment: Did you try select by id? "#active"?

Comment: I need both origin (x) and d3.event.x so I can calculate the new width for the bar but first I need to just focus the calculations on the selected bar.   I'm not familiar with id? #active.